# Sinatra Safely Set Timezone per Request

Tags: ruby, sinatra, activesupport

I'm trying to figure out how to set the timezone on a per request basis in Sinatra for a multithreaded application.

Rails provides the `:around_action` filter to handle this wherein the request is processed inside of a `Time.use_zone` block.

```
around_action :set_time_zone, if: :current_user

def set_time_zone(&block)
  Time.use_zone(current_user.time_zone, &block) 
end
```

Sinatra, however, only provides before and after filters:

```
before do
  Time.zone = current_user.time_zone
end

after do
  Time.zone = default_time_zone
end
```

That approach, however, does not seem threadsafe. What is the right way to accomplish this in Sinatra?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Setting Time.zone during a request: Thread Safe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15451637/setting-time-zone-during-a-request-thread-safe)

Answer (score 1):

I recall there being a Sinatra extension to provide `around` hooks, but can't find it. Otherwise, you'd have to put the code in each action:

```
def my_endpoint
  with_around_hooks do
    render text: "hello world"
  end
end

private

def with_around_hooks(&blk)
  # you could hypothetically put more stuff here
  Time.use_zone(current_user.time_zone, &blk) 
end
```

Hopefully someone else knows a way to wrap code around each request though